# Get JSON object node

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a json object and I want to get the value of :
entities > media > sizes > large > h

Is there a way to get it like XML -> Xpath method?

This is extra lines that is irrelevant to question just because of ...

```
{
  "created_at": "Sun, 01 Jan 2012 17:05:32 +0000",
  "entities": {
    "user_mentions": [
      {
        "screen_name": "nurdanterbiyik",
        "name": "nurdan",
        "id": 264782080,
        "id_str": "264782080",
        "indices": [
          0,
          15
        ]
      }
    ],
    "media": [
      {
        "id": 153522253777219584,
        "id_str": "153522253777219584",
        "indices": [
          44,
          64
        ],
        "media_url": "http://p.twimg.com/AiFrrSmCMAAdEID.jpg",
        "media_url_https": "https://p.twimg.com/AiFrrSmCMAAdEID.jpg",
        "url": "http://t.co/ZwHN9gvO",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/ZwHN9gvO",
        "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/emelkiraac/status/153522253773025280/photo/1",
        "type": "photo",
        "sizes": {
          "large": {
            "w": 536,
            "h": 800,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
```

Comment: Use JavascriptSerializer: you can pass a string and return an object. From there, you access the properties of the returned object and get the h.

Answer (score 8):

Using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) you have several ways to read data without having to deserialize your JSON text into objects. Here is a simplified example:

```
string json = @" {
""created_at"": ""Sun, 01 Jan 2012 17:05:32 +0000"",
  ""entities"": {
    ""media"": [{
      ""type"": ""photo"",
      ""sizes"": {
        ""large"": {
          ""w"": 536,
          ""h"": 800,
          ""resize"": ""fit""
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
int h = (int)o["entities"]["media"][0]["sizes"]["large"]["h"];
int h2 = (int)o.SelectToken("entities.media[0].sizes.large.h");
```

Comment: how do you check if o["entities"]["media"] exist?

Comment: How can I look through `media` if there were multiple blocks inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think of JSON purely as serialized objects--the first and last thing I want to do with it is to de-serialize it into the objects that I then work with.

I can't tell you the best way to do it in c#, but I've had good luck using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

JSON.NET will also let you (quote from website) "LINQ to JSON is good for situations where you are only interested in getting values from JSON, you don't have a class to serialize or deserialize to, or the JSON is radically different from your class and you need to manually read and write from your objects. LINQ to JSON allows you to easily read, create and modify JSON in .NET.", which sounds like what you are trying to do.  I've never tried it, but if all you're trying to do is get one piece of data out of that long string, then it sounds like a good alternative.